# Bootstrap datepicker is displayed on top of table heading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

In my project, I am using bootstrap datepicker and the issue I am facing is as shown :

[image: Datepicker Issue]

In the column for expiry, when I click on it, the datepicker appears on top of table column.

Here's what I used to define it :

```
 $('#hours').datetimepicker({
         format: 'HH:mm',
         collapse:true,
         sideBySide:false,
         useCurrent:false,
         showClose:true,
     });
```

What attribute am I putting wrong or am I forgetting any attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

Apply position:relative to the  of your table. will solve your issue. Here's fiddle Example

https://jsfiddle.net/znLmpgz7/1/

```
.table td{
  position:relative;
 }
```